# Should duplicates be closed even if there is no answer on the original?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Specifically - I thought of this question re: the numerous Kylo Ren naming questions - there are several and while answers have been given that could justify marking the question as answered, they simply haven't been. But, because of that, the SE platform doesn't allow flagging of a new question as duplicate because the old question isn't 'officially' answered. Should that be changed or a new method of flagging as dupe devised?

(PS - I searched for a question similar to this but didn't have much luck...so feel free to close as duplicate if needed :D

Comment: My opinion: If they're all very new questions, then consolidating them all into one sounds like a good idea even if there are no good answers yet. It may very well prevent duplicate research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### We should close one of them, not necessarily the newer

All of the reasons we close questions as duplicates still apply here, the biggest one being duplication of information. We have two questions asking the same thing; irrespective of either *having* an answer, we only *want* answers to that question to be in one place.

If neither question has an (upvoted) answer, or if both do, then we should keep the better one open, whichever one that happens to be.

If only one has an answer, we should leave that one open. Why close is when that's the one with an answer?

As far as mechanics goes, the SE system does prevent us from flagging/VTCing as a duplicate when the "target" question has no upvoted answers. This is a limitation of the SE platform that is probably not going to be changed (but if you want to petition, [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is the place to do so). What I've done in the past in situations like this is raise a custom flag and leave a comment. Moderators are able to close questions regardless of answers on either, so that neatly takes care of it.

Comment: I should also point out that I have no idea of the specifics of these Kylo Ren questions; I have been blissfully avoiding [tag:the-force-awakens] all week, and I will continue to do so until tomorrow night (bought my ticket!)

Comment: I've seen it twice already :) - enjoy!